# How can I check that a perl version is not greater than some value?

Tags: perl

To ensure a script has at least version X of perl, you can do the following

```
require 5.6.8;
```

What is the best way of checking that a version is not too recent?
(i.e. version 5.8.x if fine, but 5.9 or 5.10 are not ok).

Comment: I'd be curious to know in which context this would be useful. Perl tends to go out of its way to preserve backward compatibility.

Comment: @JB A theoretical reason: later versions of Perl may have unexpected bugs.  For instance, 5.10.0 had a memory leak related to qr//.  In certain locked down environments an older version with known bugs is safer than a new version with unknown bugs.

Comment: In my case, I have a system which includes a bunch of compiled libraries which won't work on perl 5.10.

Comment: +1 for thinking of system stability :)

Comment: Perl doesn't tend that hard to preserve backward compatibility. Features often disappear (like psuedohashes), change (like smart matching), or be binary incompatible.

Comment: Yup, I have this check in my code before I do some internal mucking around with pseudohashes: if ($] >= 5.009) { die "..." }  (Not as much because I'm sure the code will break in 5.10, but that I haven't done adequate testing there to be absolutely confident, and my firm is still not wanting to upgrade all systems to 5.10.)

Comment: @chas That would seem to make the false assumption that once a bug is introduced it will always be there.

Comment: If you are using compiled libraries, you may have to lock it down to a minor version. i.e. `5.6.0` .. `5.6.999`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This code will die if the version of Perl is greater than 5.8.9:

```
die "woah, that is a little too new" unless $] <= 5.008009;
```

You can read more about `$]` in [`perldoc perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%5d).

Answer (score 8):

You can use the special `$^V` variable to check the version. From [perldoc perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%24%5eV):

```
$^V

The revision, version, and subversion of the Perl interpreter, represented as a 
version object.

This variable first appeared in perl 5.6.0; earlier versions of perl will see an    
undefined value. Before perl 5.10.0 $^V was represented as a v-string.
```

You can use $^V in a string comparison, e.g.

```
if ( $^V lt 'v5.10.0' )
```

If you may be running on a perl earlier than 5.6.0, you'll need to use `$]` which returns a simple integer.

Comment: I don't think that string comparison will work without version.pm (which many versions of 5.6+ perl don't necessarily have).  Did you mean ($^V lt v5.10.0)?  I don't see any reason to favor $^V over $].

Comment: If you're trying to use old perls, this isn't the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to do this:

```
no 5.010;
```

Comment: Doesn't really work: try `no 5.011` and you'll get an error that `feature bundle "5.11.0" is not supported by Perl 5.10.0`. Rather broken....