# How can I ensure a Perl script works with an older version?

Tags: perl

Similar but different to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377469/how-can-i-check-that-a-perl-version-is-not-greater-than-some-value).

I am writing a perl script, foo.pl.  I use Perl 5.10 on my machine to run foo.pl.  I have to also make sure that foo.pl can be run by Perl 5.8.8.  Is there a way to do so without just installing v5.8.8?

Comment: Perl is *very* easy to build and install; there's no check that will give you total confidence of compatibility. Just install 5.8.8.

Comment: Look into perlbrew. It will allow you to install multiple versions of perl and switch between them for testing.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041136/perl-version-specific-syntax-resource http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2500892/how-can-i-test-when-a-feature-was-added-to-perl

Comment: Joe - Have you tried to actually find a linux binary for 5.8.8?  I tried all morning and could not find it.

Comment: He said "build". Since it's easy to build it should be easy to find a binary on your local machine after building one. As gpojd said: check out perlbrew.

Answer (score 4):

[perlver](http://p3rl.org/perlver), [Perl::MinimumVersion](http://p3rl.org/Perl%3a%3aMinimumVersion)**[::Fast](http://p3rl.org/Perl%3a%3aMinimumVersion%3a%3aFast)**

Comment: That is an awesome thing to know about.